# Unit test failing when importing a header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest

I'm trying to implement unit tests in my project in Objective-C.
The problem is I don't have any error messages when the build fails, and after few tests, I can't figure out how to perform the build.

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    self.order = [[TLSOrderEntity alloc] init];

    self.calculateVatDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

    self.price100 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:100];
    self.price200 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:200];

    self.tax5 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.5];
    self.tax10 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:10];
    self.tax20 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:20];
}
```

This method is fine, it can be builded, and works fine. When i'm trying to import an other header, and trying to alloc the corresponding object, the build instantly fails.

```
#import "TLSOrderLineEntity.h"

- (void)testExample {
    TLSOrderLineEntity *line1 = [TLSOrderLineEntity createEntityLineWithName:@"PRODUIT" price:self.price100 tax:self.tax10 extraLines:nil];
}
```

I also have other interfaces to get without errors private methods, and to declare few attibutes:

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TLSOrderTaxManager.h"

@interface TLSOrderTaxManager (Test)

+ (NSDictionary *)calculateVatForLines:(TLSOrderEntity *)order;

@end

@interface TLSTaxTests : XCTestCase

@property (nonatomic, strong) TLSOrderEntity    *order;
@property (nonatomic, strong) TLSOrderLineEntity *orderLine;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary      *calculateVatDictionary;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber          *price100;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber          *price200;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber          *tax5;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber          *tax10;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber          *tax20;

@end
```

As I said before, I don't have any clue to understand why it fails.
Is there a dependency problem? Or should I compile the corresponding .m in order to include them?

Thank you for your advices!

Comment: Hi. Please add an error message which you got from xcode.

Comment: Hello. That's exactly the problem I have actually. Xcode doesn't provide any error message, even if I enable the test. It just display "Build failed". Is there a way to display the error messages ?

Comment: Can you add a screenshots? The `Build failed`-message is not give any information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you provide error message? Try to tap on icon with exclamation mark embedded in triangle in left panel:

[image]

Try to press icons in bottom of this panel(they are responsible for errors/warnings filtration). Maybe you've disabled errors before.

As for your problem description it seems like you haven't added this file to test target. Try to select TLSOrderLineEntity.m and check test target for this file:
[image]

Comment: Perfect ! I didn't added the file to the test target, you were right !
It seems to work fine by now, I did not enabled the test as well, that's why i didn't get any message.
Thank you !

Comment: No. Files in the production target should NOT be included in the test target.

Comment: @JonReid why do you think so? As far as I read it's common practice(for example in the book "Test Driven iOS Development")

Comment: Graham Lee says, “Sadly, at the time of publication, the linker problem still needed to be worked around.” For more, see my book review http://qualitycoding.org/test-driven-ios-development-book/ and find "Unit test bundles should link just fine"

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this. But what are bad consequences if we will include files from production target to tests? Could you explain please

Comment: @curious You'd essentially have to maintain the test target in parallel with the production target. Every file gets included in two places. That brings along all the linked libraries. Every change to the production target must be repeated in the test target, which is time-consuming and error-prone. When testing, everything would be built twice, slowing down your feedback loop.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JonReid. It sounds meaningfully. I've tried to exclude my product's files from test's target and tests are still executing.

Answer (score 4):

A correctly configured test target can access everything in the production target.

In the test target's "Build Settings":

- Set "Test Host" to your app. Something like `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/MyApp.app/MyApp`
- Set "Bundle Loader" to `$(TEST_HOST)`

In the test target's "General" settings:

- Specify the Host Application. Make sure the check box "Allow testing Host Application APIs" is selected.

[image: Host Application setting]

Answer (score 0):

If you just added new production target class file and if you try to import it's header (even if it's '.m' file is added to the unit tests target) it will fail because XCode may not have build it's header search paths for the new class. Especially if you add new directory for the new file. In this case simply clean the project and this fixes the issue.